# PHP uniqid duplicado

Tags: php, mysqli

Intento insertar registros en un loop generando un ID unico con uniqid, y el problema que tengo es que me genera valores duplicados, por lo tanto me da error al insertar el nuevo registro.

```html
<?php
//......
do { 
$remid = uniqid('rem_'); 
 
    
   
 // Datos 

$IdPedidoDB = $rowFinalizados["id_pedido"];
$IdPedidoTrafico = $rowFinalizados["id_pedido_trafico"];
$IdCliente=$rowFinalizados["id_cliente"];
$IdSucursal=$rowFinalizados["id_sucursal"];
$IdInterno=$rowFinalizados["id_interno"];
$Solicitante=$rowFinalizados["solicitante"];
$NumRef=$rowFinalizados["numref"]; 
$FechaLlamado=$rowFinalizados["fechallamado"];
$HoraLlamado=$rowFinalizados["horallamado"];
$FechaServicio=$rowFinalizados["fechaservicio"]; 
$HoraServicio=$rowFinalizados["horaservicio"]; 
$Demora=$rowFinalizados["demora"]; 
$PedidoObservaciones=$rowFinalizados["observaciones"]; 
$TipoServicio=$rowFinalizados["tiposervicio"]; 
$Direccion=$rowFinalizados["direccion"]; 
$Nro=$rowFinalizados["nro"]; 
$Piso=$rowFinalizados["piso"]; 
$Depto=$rowFinalizados["depto"];
$Telefono=$rowFinalizados["telefono"];
$Localidad=$rowFinalizados["localidad"];
$Provincia=$rowFinalizados["provincia"];
$IdEmpleado=$rowFinalizados["asignado_id_empleado"];

$query = "INSERT INTO remitos(id_remito_registro,periodo,id_pedido,id_pedido_trafico, id_cliente, id_sucursal, id_interno, solicitante, numref, fechallamado, horallamado, fechaservicio, horaservicio, demora, pedido_descripcion, tiposervicio, direccion, nro, piso, depto, telefono, localidad, provincia, asignado_id_empleado) VALUES ('".$remid."','".$periodo."','".$IdPedidoDB."','".$IdPedidoTrafico."','".$IdCliente."','".$IdSucursal."','".$IdInterno."','".$Solicitante."','".$NumRef."','".$FechaLlamado."','".$HoraLlamado."','".$FechaServicio."','".$HoraServicio."','".$Demora."','".$PedidoObservaciones."','".$TipoServicio."','".$Direccion."','".$Nro."','".$Piso."','".$Depto."','".$Telefono."','".$Localidad."','".$Provincia."','".$IdEmpleado."')";

if ($mysqli->query($query) === TRUE){
    echo "";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>";
}


   }
      
//........      
?>
```

Comment: El campo "id_remito_registro" es una primary key auto incrementable?

Comment: ¿Por qué usas `uniqid()` aquí? ¿Qué tiene que ver con tu tabla o con tu base de datos?

Comment: @GabrielMoreyra no es autoincrementable porque supuestamente uniqid genera ID únicos

Comment: @A.Cedano necesito que sean valores aleatorios alfanuméricos que si lo dejo en manos de MySQL solo incrementaría de a uno (según tengo entendido)

Comment: Sí, mysql va a incrementar de 1 en 1 o de `n` en `n` , pero ¿por qué te planteas la solución así, hay una justificación? ¿esa columna debe ser llave primaria? ¿por qué no te sirve un auto-incremental gestionado por el manejador de base de datos? Como lo haces ahora no te asegura nada que en cualquier momento se genere un valor repetido, como de hecho parece estar ocurriendo. No me parece una buena solución generar un valor que parece debe ser único sin contar con el manejador de base de datos.

Comment: @A.Cedano si, es llave primaria y única. Lo único que no tiene definido es que sea autoincrementable

Comment: Entonces es a todas luces un error lo que estás haciendo. Si esa es la llave primaria la defines como tal, le dices que es auto-increment y el manejador se encarga del resto. Es más al hacer eso ni siquiera tienes que preocuparte de poner esa columna en el `INSERT`, la omites y el manejador por cada fila te crea un ID único. Solamente te estás complicando la vida al querer resolver una situación que el manejador hace mucho mejor que tú. Por otra parte, cuando necesites usar esa columna para relacionarla con otra tabla, no es lo mismo nunca tener un identificador numérico que uno alfanumérico.

Comment: @A.Cedano entonces optaré por este modo, así no me complico.

Comment: Claro claro, hacer lo contrario sería sub-estimar las capacidades de tu manejador de base de datos. Es como tener un piloto de avión cualificado y echarte a volar con uno que sólo ha manejado aviones de juguete a control remoto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haciendo esto:

```
$remid = uniqid('rem_');
```

Para luego usar `$remind` como valor de la llave primaria en tu tabla significa incurrir en un triple error:

1. Ignorar las capacidades del manejador de base de datos
2. Sobre cargar el código innecesariamente generando números aleatorios
3. Exponer los datos a inconsistencias y generar una dificultad añadida si esa tabla tiene que relacionarse con otra mediante la columna que reciba el valor generado en `$remid`

Si como has dicho en comentarios la intención es dar valor a una columna que en la tabla debe hacer el papel de llave primaria, deja que el manejador se ocupe de ello, declarando la columna [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html), por ejemplo:

```
id_remito_registro  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Haciendo eso, cada vez que se inserte una fila el manejador asignará a esa columna un valor incremental numérico.

Para las inserciones incluso puedes omitir esa columna:

```
INSERT INTO remitos 
    (
        periodo,
        id_pedido,
        ...
    )   
    VALUES 
    (
        valor_periodo
        valor_id_pedido
        ...

    );
```

El valor de `id_remito_registro` se establecerá sólo.

---

> **NOTA SOBRE LA SEGURIDAD:** El código PHP que estás usando es altamente vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Sugiero que
>   investigues sobre el tema cuando puedas y que apliques consultas
>   preparadas en tu código para prevenir ese riesgo.